# Get the side a player is looking on the block | bukkit

Tags: bukkit

It is possible to get the Block the Player actually is looking at.

```
p.getTargetBlock()
```

But is there a way to get the side of the block that the player is looking at?
(***top, down, north, south, east, west*** side of the block)
I haven't found a function that will do that. Does it give me something, that I can use to find this side?

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do? It's quite possible that knowing the block face prior to any events is not really necessary.

Comment: I try to get the side of the Block, where the player wants to place a block before he has placed it.

Comment: For what purpose though?

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented a Utility method for achieving this given the `AxisAlignedBB` (NMS) of the Block the player is targeting. This block can be obtained by `Player#getTargetBlock()` as mentioned in the question or with a custom raycast algorithm.

```
public static BlockFace blockFaceCollide(Vector startLocation, Vector direction, AxisAlignedBB objectBoundry){

    double constant = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    BlockFace blockFace = null;

    double directionX = direction.getX();
    double directionY = direction.getY();
    double directionZ = direction.getZ();


    if(directionY > 0){
        double b = objectBoundry.b - startLocation.getY();
        double tempConstant = b / directionY;
        if(tempConstant > 0 && tempConstant < constant){
            double xAtCollide = tempConstant * directionX + startLocation.getX();
            double zAtCollide = tempConstant * directionZ + startLocation.getZ();
            if (between(xAtCollide, objectBoundry.a, objectBoundry.d, 0)
                    && between(zAtCollide, objectBoundry.c, objectBoundry.f, 0)) {
                constant = tempConstant;
                blockFace = BlockFace.DOWN;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        double e = objectBoundry.e - startLocation.getY();
        double tempConstant = e / directionY;
        if (tempConstant > 0 && tempConstant < constant) {
            double xAtCollide = tempConstant * directionX + startLocation.getX();
            double zAtCollide = tempConstant * directionZ + startLocation.getZ();
            if (between(xAtCollide, objectBoundry.a, objectBoundry.d, 0)
                    && between(zAtCollide, objectBoundry.c, objectBoundry.f, 0)) {
                constant = tempConstant;
                blockFace = BlockFace.UP;
            }
        }
    }

    if(directionX < 0) {
        double d = objectBoundry.d - startLocation.getX();
        double tempConstant = d / directionX;
        if (tempConstant > 0 && tempConstant < constant) {
            double yAtCollide = tempConstant * directionY + startLocation.getY();
            double zAtCollide = tempConstant * directionZ + startLocation.getZ();
            if (between(yAtCollide, objectBoundry.b, objectBoundry.e, 0)
                    && between(zAtCollide, objectBoundry.c, objectBoundry.f, 0)) {
                constant = tempConstant;
                blockFace = BlockFace.EAST;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        double a = objectBoundry.a - startLocation.getX();
        double tempConstant = a / directionX;
        if (tempConstant > 0 && tempConstant < constant) {
            double yAtCollide = tempConstant * directionY + startLocation.getY();
            double zAtCollide = tempConstant * directionZ + startLocation.getZ();
            if (between(yAtCollide, objectBoundry.b, objectBoundry.e, 0)
                    && between(zAtCollide, objectBoundry.c, objectBoundry.f, 0)) {
                constant = tempConstant;
                blockFace = BlockFace.WEST;
            }
        }
    }

    if(directionZ > 0) {
        double c = objectBoundry.c - startLocation.getZ();
        double tempConstant = c / directionZ;
        if(tempConstant > 0 && tempConstant < constant) {
            double yAtCollide = tempConstant * directionY + startLocation.getY();
            double xAtCollide = tempConstant * directionX + startLocation.getX();
            if (between(yAtCollide, objectBoundry.b, objectBoundry.e, 0)
                    && between(xAtCollide, objectBoundry.a, objectBoundry.d, 0)) {
                blockFace = BlockFace.NORTH;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        double f = objectBoundry.f - startLocation.getZ();
        double tempConstant = f / directionZ;
        if(tempConstant < constant) {
            double yAtCollide = tempConstant * directionY + startLocation.getY();
            double xAtCollide = tempConstant * directionX + startLocation.getX();
            if (between(yAtCollide, objectBoundry.b, objectBoundry.e, 0)
                    && between(xAtCollide, objectBoundry.a, objectBoundry.d, 0)) {
                blockFace = BlockFace.SOUTH;
            }
        }
    }
    return blockFace;
}

public static boolean between(double num, double a, double b, double EOF) {
    if (a <= b)
        return num + EOF >= a && num - EOF <= b;
    return num + EOF >= b && num - EOF <= a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is way to get the block they are looking at, however you can get the block face that they click by using `PlayerInteractEvent` and its `getBlockFace()` method.

**EDIT:** Check out [this](https://bukkit.org/threads/solved-player-direction.72789/) thread on the bukkit forums.

**EDIT 2:** Or as mentioned in [this](https://bukkit.org/threads/find-blockface-player-is-targeting.145903/) thread, you can try putting this in a `PlayerMoveEvent`:

```
List<Block> blocks = event.getPlayer().getLastTwoTargetBlocks(null, 10);
if (blocks.size() > 1) 
    face = blocks.get(1).getFace(blocks.get(0));
```

Comment: Jeah. But I have to know which side he is looking at, bevore he places the block.